# Dispatcher.BeginInvoke problems

Tags: c#, dispatcher

I'm getting "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Action)'" for this code.

```
private void ResponseCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
        HttpWebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(result) as HttpWebResponse;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( () => {
                try
                {
                    XDocument resultsXml = XDocument.Load(sr);
                    QueryCompleted(new QueryCompletedEventArgs(resultsXml));
                }
                catch (XmlException e)
                {
                    XDocument errorXml = new XDocument(new XElement("error", e.Message));
                    QueryCompleted(new QueryCompletedEventArgs(errorXml));
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the UI thread create a dispatcher -- Dispatcher UIDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher; -- Then in the above method call BeginInvoke like this -- UIDispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>... --

Comment: see this one also.. http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/89243/534524.aspx

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The error indicates that you need an instance of `Dispatcher` to call `BeginInvoke` since it is an instance method.  Where you get that instance depends on where you want to dispatch a call.

Perhaps you could try using the static property `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` to get the instance of the dispatcher for the current thread and then call `BeginInvoke` on that instance.  Either that or somehow get a dispatcher instance to your method from the particular thread you want to call to.

Comment: Given this is an async callback, and assuming he actually wants to be running the invoked code on the UI thread, Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher won't actually do what he needs.  But you're right under other circumstances (or if I've guessed wrong about his requirements).

Comment: Because if this is an async callback, it's running on a thread pool thread, not the UI thread.  So Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher will create a new Dispatcher for the calling thread, i.e. the thread pool thread.  And so the invoked code will run on that newly created Dispatcher's thread, i.e. the calling thread, i.e. the thread pool thread -- not the UI thread.  (Of course, my assumptions may be wrong here.)

Comment: I actually ended up taking a different route. I used the AsyncOperation/AsyncOperationManager to fire the QueryCompleted event on the UI thread. This way I don't need the ugly dispatcher code in my clean viewmodels.

Comment: If you want to use Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher you have to grab a copy of it from the UI thread and store it (like on Form_Load for instance), then you can call that stored version of the property from your background worker threads. -- If you were to grab the Dispatacher.CurrentDispatcher from the background threads directly, it will return the dispatcher for that background thread, which would be useless, since you're already in that context.

Answer (score 22):

Things have changed a bit since the last answer was posted for this question.
`System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` is now `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by this?  Nothing in .NET 4.0 has changed in this regards.  Did you mean that it got changed in .NET 4.5?

Comment: Deployment:  is in Silverlight